Asymptotic growth of twisted alexander polynomials and hyperbolic volume for infinite families of knots
Let $\{K_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an infinite family of hyperbolic knots with increasing crossing number, and let $\rho_n: \pi_1(S^3 \setminus K_n) \to SL_N(\mathbb{C})$ be a sequence of irreducible representations.
Denote by $\Delta_{K_n, \rho_n}(t)$ the twisted Alexander polynomial associated to $K_n$ and $\rho_n$. Let $vol(K_n)$ denote the hyperbolic volume of the knot complement $S^3 \setminus K_n$.
We define the Mahler measure of a polynomial $f(t) = a_n t^n + \dots + a_0$ as
$$M(f) = |a_n| \prod_{i=1}^n \max(1, |\alpha_i|),$$
where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $f(t)$.
Under what conditions on the family $\{K_n\}$ and the sequence of representations $\{\rho_n\}$ does the following limit exist and, if it exists, what can be said about its value:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log M(\Delta_{K_n, \rho_n}(t))}{vol(K_n)}$$

Have you seen this paper? http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/oai/2022/71/8937/8937.xml
